# How can a webpage tell if it is open in a webapp view without referrer?

Tags: javascript, android, ios

For Android and for iOS, can you detect if a page is being opened in a webapp view using just JavaScript without referrer information? For example where the script is on the second page accessed on the same domain?

Comment: I would look into https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API

Comment: Can you describe what you hope to accomplish by detecting if the page is being opened in a webapp view?

Comment: I would like some JavaScript functionality on the page to be off when in the webview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way we have achieved this is to modify the UserAgent string in our native app. We insert the name of our app to the end of the useragent string.

Then our WebApp can tell if it is being loaded within the Android or IOS native app.

Other methods could be having the Native app always pass a specific query string, like ?native=true, or hash, #!?native=true.

Comment: It looks like you have to have very fine control of both the app and the page to set this up. I have not been able to find a better answer. I believe it is against the standard to send referrer information from something that is not a web page, but parameters are a good idea, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to control both of those websites, build some sort of api to push and read data on the websites open on the tabs.

Browsers themselves do not offer an api for this purpose.

If you would build your own custom web browser app for iOS or Android, I'm sure you could implement what ever api's to let your tabs know what pages are open on other tabs.